# nickel.rs post redirect not found

Tags: rust, nickel

I am using nickel.rs, PostgreSQL, and Angular.js. I can insert into my table with an HTTP POST:

```
// insert
{
    let conn = shared_connection.clone();
    router.post("/api/movies", middleware! { |request, mut response|
        let conn = conn.lock().unwrap();
        let stmt = match conn.prepare("insert into movie (title, releaseYear, director, genre)
            values ($1, $2, $3, $4)") {
            Ok(stmt) => stmt,
            Err(e) => {
                return response.send(format!("Preparing query failed: {}", e));
            }
        };

        let movie = request.json_as::<MovieInsert>().unwrap();
        match stmt.execute(&[
            &movie.title.to_string(),
            &movie.releaseYear,
            &movie.director.to_string(),
            &movie.genre.to_string()
        ]) {
            Ok(v) => println!("Inserting movie was Success."),
            Err(e) => println!("Inserting movie failed. => {:?}", e),
        };

        // ERROR (1)
        // return response.set(Location("/".into()));

    });
}
```

I know this works fine because the row is inserted in the PostgreSQL table. However, the Chrome web browser shows an error:

```
POST http://localhost:6767/api/movies 404 (Not Found)
```

I also added the code in `ERROR (1)` line

```
response.set(Location("/".into()));
```

however, console show the error.

```
 expected `core::result::Result<nickel::middleware::Action<nickel::response::Response<'mw, _>, nickel::response::Response<'mw, _, hyper::net::Streaming>>, nickel::nickel_error::NickelError<'mw, _>>`,
    found `&mut nickel::response::Response<'_, _>`
(expected enum `core::result::Result`,
    found &-ptr)
```

Now it is my code applied what Shepmaster said.

```
// insert
{
    let conn = shared_connection.clone();
    router.post("/api/movies", middleware! { |request, mut response|
        let conn = conn.lock().unwrap();
        let stmt = match conn.prepare("insert into movie (title, releaseYear, director, genre)
            values ($1, $2, $3, $4)") {
            Ok(stmt) => stmt,
            Err(e) => {
                return response.send(format!("Preparing query failed: {}", e));
            }
        };

        let movie = request.json_as::<MovieInsert>().unwrap();
        match stmt.execute(&[
            &movie.title.to_string(),
            &movie.releaseYear,
            &movie.director.to_string(),
            &movie.genre.to_string()
        ]) {
            Ok(v) => println!("Inserting movie was Success."),
            Err(e) => println!("Inserting movie failed. => {:?}", e),
        };

        response.set(StatusCode::PermanentRedirect)
            .set(Location("/".into()));
        ""
    });
}
```

but the error occurred.

src/main.rs:155:18: 155:43 error: the trait `modifier::Modifier<nickel::response::Response<'_, _>>` is not implemented for the type `hyper::header::common::location::Location` [E0277]
src/main.rs:155                 .set(Location("/".into()));

**finally I fix like this!**

```
            Ok(v) => {
                println!("Inserting movie was Success.");
                response.set(StatusCode::Ok);
            },
            Err(e) => println!("Inserting movie failed. => {:?}", e),
        };

        //response.set(StatusCode::PermanentRedirect)
        //    .set(Location("/".into()));
        //""
        return response.send("");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code, as currently listed, doesn't make any sense. There's nothing returned from your route handler:

```
match ... {
    Ok(v) => println!("Inserting movie was Success."),
    Err(e) => println!("Inserting movie failed. => {:?}", e),
};
```

Because nothing about the database or the frontend framework is important, your code is equivalent to this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nickel;

use nickel::{Nickel, HttpRouter};

fn main() {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();

    server.post("/api/movies", middleware! { |request, mut response|
        println!("Hello");
    });

    server.listen("127.0.0.1:6767");
}
```

If you return something from the handler, then the HTTP status code changes from a 404 to a 200.

If you'd like to redirect somewhere, you need to explicitly change the status code. The documentation for [`Response::set`](http://docs.nickel.rs/nickel/struct.Response.html#method.set) happens to have an example:

```
server.get("/a", middleware! { |_, mut res|
    res.set(StatusCode::PermanentRedirect)
       .set(Location("http://nickel.rs".into()));

    ""
});
```

Note that an empty string is returned, similar to before. You were trying to return the `Response` type directly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying and fixing my Jangrish.
I added you code but type was different so error occurred.
I update my question.

Comment: finally i got success. Thank you. Finally code is it